# How to implement a Quartz.NET job in ASP.NET MVC with UnitOfWorkPattern on EF Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application, with EF Code First for data layer. I have implemented a Unit of work pattern, I’m binding context of the unit of work on HttpContext.Current.Items[SomeKey] collection. Unit of work is created and committed in OnActionExecuting/Executed events on controller.  I’m instantiating repositories using Windsor Castle.

Now I need to use Quartz.net to run a job periodically in my app, this job need also use few repositories. The problem is, that in a SchedulerJob implementation, there is no HttpContext available (indeed). How can I instantiate a repository (which takes UnitOfWorkFactory as constructor parameter) from a Quartz.net Job in that case? How can I substitute missing HttpContext? I will probably need to implement another  UnitOfWorkFactory, but I’m not sure where I can bind my context and how to register different factory just for Quartz.net thread. Can you please show me a way or pattern? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit of work implementation belongs to the business logic layer and should not depend on a specific presentation layer such as MVC.

I made a custom UnitOfWorkScope that I've used in a couple of projects: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/10/make-the-dbcontext-ambient-with-unitofworkscope/

Comment: I agree with your statement, that the unit of work should not be dependent on UI layer. I read your article, but I cannot see from it, how to combine your approach with the repository pattern and DI. I would like to have instances of repositories (or facades) injected by DI into my controller. How then get a repository be aware of current UnitOfWorkScope?

Comment: It works similar to a TransactionScope. Just create a new UOW in a repository and it will use the DbContext of a UOW opened by a gäller. It handles the DI but also provides voting for handling saving (or not).

Comment: That seems to be OK for one repository, but what if I need execute an complex operation on more repositories (few calls to few different repositories), and I would like to have this complex operation under one scope? I also noticed, that you are using a private ThreadStatic variable (scopedDbContext), is this approach safe in ASP MVC? I used HttpContext.Current.Items collection to store context, because it is unique instance for each HTTP request. Is it guaranteed, that the thread that is serving my request will not switch to another request in the middle of UnitOfWorkScope block?

Comment: To keep calls to multiple repositories to use the same DbContext the calls to them must be wrapped in one UOW. I typically open a UOW in my action methods. As long as you're not using threading or async methods everything will be run on one thread. It probably will fail with a sync actions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, at the end I decided to refactor my UOW and implement it without depedency on HttpContext. I will also remove the Quertz.NET job and implement it's functionality via MSSQL Job.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider writing your own job factory and injecting your repositories there. I wrote a post on how to do this [here](http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2012/07/23/creating-a-custom-quartz-net-jobfactory/). Windsor also has a [facitlity](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Quartz-Net-integration&NS=Contrib&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for integrating Quartz.net directly.

One last comment... you shouldn't host Quartz.Net in your web app if you are going to schedule long running jobs or if you are going to schedule jobs to run periodically. IIS process recycling will not let your scheduler run properly. A windows service is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I come to conclusion that I will remove the Quartz job and implement the functionality as MSSQL Job, which will be triggered periodically. Unfortunately I cannot install windows service on the server, because it is a commercial web hosting server and the admins wont allow install anything custom on it.