# How to implement scheduled task on EF (DB first) entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, scheduled-tasks

I am quite new to `Asp.net` and have a website using `Entity Framework`. Every night, I need to do some work on my `Person` entities.
Thus I installed `Quartz.Net` et tried to use it this way in `Global.asax` :

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Quartz" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Quartz.Impl" %>

<script runat="server">

    private IScheduler Scheduler { get; set; }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        Scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail dailyReset = JobBuilder.Create<ApplicationJobs.DailyReset>()
            .WithIdentity("dailyReset", "group1")
            .Build();

        ITrigger dailyResetTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("dailyResetTrigger", "group1")
            .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(3, 0, 0))
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInHours(24)
            .RepeatForever())
        .Build()

        Scheduler.ScheduleJob(dailyReset, dailyResetTrigger);
    }
</script>
```

Then my ApplicationJobs class :

```
public class ApplicationJobs : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public class DailyReset : IJob
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
            {
                foreach (Person person in uof.Context.Persons)
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the UnitOfWork :

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private const string _httpContextKey = "_unitOfWork";
    private MyEntities _dbContext;

    public static UnitOfWork Current
    {
        get { return (UnitOfWork)HttpContext.Current.Items[_httpContextKey]; }
    }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[_httpContextKey] = this;
    }

    public MyEntities Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dbContext == null)
                _dbContext = new MyEntities();

            return _dbContext;
        }
    }
}
```

But `using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())` is not working because of `HttpContext.Current.Items[_httpContextKey] = this;` in uow's constructor ; I read that `HttpContext.Current` was not available in `Application_Start`.

In read related posts, notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119057/how-to-implement-a-quartz-net-job-in-asp-net-mvc-with-unitofworkpattern-on-ef-co) but I don't really understand if I do need to create something like `UnitOfWorkScope` [described here](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/10/make-the-dbcontext-ambient-with-unitofworkscope/), or if there could be a way to do that as it currently is.

Then is there any clean and safe way to schedule some task which would use my `UnitOfWork` in order to update entities ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem come from the fact that when your job will run, it wil be called by the quartz scheduller, not from an http request (even if the job is in an ASP website).

So HttpContext.Current will be most likely null.

Keep in mind when using Quartz that you shoudl see it as a totally paralle process to your website, almost like a separate service.

If you need to pass "argument" to your job, you can use the job data map

```
JobDataMap dataMap = jobContext.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
```

(see here for more info : http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html)

If you need to access your job, just use the same key and group when creating a jobkey (the one you used in **WithIdentity**

Note that it is recommended for entity context to be alive only for the time of the action you need it, so you could probably just instantiate a new context at the start of the job and dispose it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! It is my first time doing this kind of thing so it really helps. I took a look at the tutorial you linked but I don't really understand what could be done with `JobDataMap` in that case. I understand how it works but what argument could I pass to the job in order to be able to use my entities in it ?

Comment: The jobdatamap alow you to pass parametter, (string, number and object) during the job creation for the futur running job. In your case, you shouldn't need to pass argument but just use a `using(_dbContext = new MyEntities())` at the start of the job execute part

Comment: This works perfectly well, I can't believe I did not even thought about using `new MyEntities()` directly. Many thanks (for your comment about Quartz scheduler keeping being alive as well), you made my day !

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not executing the job within a web request. As in, web request starts, you check outstanding work, do work if required, request ends. Without a web request you have no context - as the context is for the lifetime of the web request and accessible via the request thread.

Another issue you're going to have is app-pool, using default settings, may end if there's no activity. So you would need a way to keep it alive.

An alternative method is to use something like win task scheduler to hit the website to kick off the work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Plebsori ! I have to admit that I am not really familiar with web requests yet but you helped me understand what is going on. I was not especially aware of app-pool either but I will look into it. Then from your point of view what would be best ; find a way to keep it alive or triggers it with a task scheduler ?

Comment: I can tell by experience that the Quartz Scheduler keep alive the app pool whitout any specific configuration, so you don't have to worry about that ^^

Comment: I've seen various solutions to this problem. None are great and all have pro/cons. I'd suggest a quick google for 'asp.net background work' or similar

Comment: If quartz scheduler actually keeps being alive without any specific conf as Remy said that would be perfect, I think that I will take a look at it anyway just to be sure and to learn a little bit more about it ! Many thanks to both of you, your answers were really relevant and helped me ;)

Comment: @RemyGrandin I'm fairly certain the app-pool will be put to sleep or torn down. Do you have a link that states otherwise?

Comment: No link but it's an experience ascertainment : I deved a webapp (SESM) that rely hevily on jobs to check for update availability every x minute / hours and I even tried to test it with a check every 6 hours (the website was local and no request was made) and the job still fired fine. The app is currently used on about 200 servers whith various usage load and not a single time I had jobs not fireing because the app pool was put to sleep. I may be because Quartz.net run it's own thread to check time and fire jobs when needed, which would prevent the app pool from being "inactive"